# passing data (currentPage) to instance as a parameter in react Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to call a method so I can paginate data from an API by passing the currentPage as a parameter, but I don't know what am I getting wrong. I have managed to pass the props like **client_id** but I couldn't deal with **currentPage**

The method **onPageChanged** should set the state of currentPage and then launch the request so I can fetch the posts of the currentPage

The instance looks like this:

```
instance.fetchConfig = (params) => {
  return instance.get(
    "/reiews?client_id=" + params.client_id + "&?page=" + params.currentPage,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + params.token,
      },
    }
  );
};
```

Here is my App component :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.conteneur = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      allPosts: null,
      currentPage: null,
      loading: false,
      widgetStatus: true,
      params: {
        client_id: null,
        localstore_id: null,
        token: null,
        currentPage: null,
      },
    };
  }

  onPageChanged = (data) => {
    const currentPage = data.selected;
    this.setState(
      {
        currentPage: currentPage,
      },
      () => {
        this.receivedData();
      }
    );
    console.log(data);
  };

  receivedData = () => {
    let newData = { ...this.state };

    newData.params = {
      client_id: this.props.client,
      localstore_id: this.props.shop,
      token: this.props.token,
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage,
    };

    Api.fetchWidgetConfig(newData.params)
      .catch((error) => {
        if (typeof error.message !== "undefined") {
          newData.widgetStatus = false;
          this.setState(newData);
        }

        return { data: { data: [] } };
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.status === "success") {
          return response.data.data;
        }
        this.setState({
          posts: [...response.data.posts.items],
          allPosts: response.data.posts.total,
          loading: false,
        });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    this.receivedData();
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is the pagination component :

```
const LEFT_PAGE = "LEFT";
const RIGHT_PAGE = "RIGHT";

const range = (from, to, step = 1) => {
  let i = from;
  const range = [];

  while (i <= to) {
    range.push(i);
    i += step;
  }

  return range;
};

class Paginate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { totalRecords = null, pageLimit = 5, pageNeighbours = 0 } = props;

    this.pageLimit = typeof pageLimit === "number" ? pageLimit : 5;
    this.totalRecords = typeof totalRecords === "number" ? totalRecords : 0;

    this.pageNeighbours =
      typeof pageNeighbours === "number"
        ? Math.max(0, Math.min(pageNeighbours, 2))
        : 0;

    this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.pageLimit);

    this.state = { currentPage: 1 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.gotoPage(1);
  }

  gotoPage = (page) => {
    const { onPageChanged = (f) => f } = this.props;

    const currentPage = Math.max(0, Math.min(page, this.totalPages));

    const paginationData = {
      currentPage,
      totalPages: this.totalPages,
      pageLimit: this.pageLimit,
      totalRecords: this.totalRecords,
    };

    this.setState({ currentPage }, () => onPageChanged(paginationData));
  };

  handleClick = (page, evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.gotoPage(page);
  };

  handleMoveLeft = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.gotoPage(this.state.currentPage - this.pageNeighbours * 2 - 1);
  };

  handleMoveRight = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.gotoPage(this.state.currentPage + this.pageNeighbours * 2 + 1);
  };

  fetchPageNumbers = () => {
    const totalPages = this.totalPages;
    const currentPage = this.state.currentPage;
    const pageNeighbours = this.pageNeighbours;

    const totalNumbers = this.pageNeighbours * 2 + 3;
    const totalBlocks = totalNumbers + 2;

    if (totalPages > totalBlocks) {
      let pages = [];

      const leftBound = currentPage - pageNeighbours;
      const rightBound = currentPage + pageNeighbours;
      const beforeLastPage = totalPages - 1;

      const startPage = leftBound > 2 ? leftBound : 2;
      const endPage = rightBound < beforeLastPage ? rightBound : beforeLastPage;

      pages = range(startPage, endPage);

      const pagesCount = pages.length;
      const singleSpillOffset = totalNumbers - pagesCount - 1;

      const leftSpill = startPage > 2;
      const rightSpill = endPage < beforeLastPage;

      const leftSpillPage = LEFT_PAGE;
      const rightSpillPage = RIGHT_PAGE;

      if (leftSpill && !rightSpill) {
        const extraPages = range(startPage - singleSpillOffset, startPage - 1);
        pages = [leftSpillPage, ...extraPages, ...pages];
      } else if (!leftSpill && rightSpill) {
        const extraPages = range(endPage + 1, endPage + singleSpillOffset);
        pages = [...pages, ...extraPages, rightSpillPage];
      } else if (leftSpill && rightSpill) {
        pages = [leftSpillPage, ...pages, rightSpillPage];
      }

      return [1, ...pages, totalPages];
    }

    return range(1, totalPages);
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.totalRecords) return null;

    if (this.totalPages === 1) return null;

    const { currentPage } = this.state;
    const pages = this.fetchPageNumbers();

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <PaginateWrapper>
          {pages.map((page, index) => {
            if (page === LEFT_PAGE)
              return (
                <PaginateBtn
                  key={index}
                  aria-label="Previous"
                  onClick={this.handleMoveLeft}
                >
                  <IconPrev
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M15 19l-7-7 7-7"
                    />
                  </IconPrev>
                  Précédent
                </PaginateBtn>
              );

            if (page === RIGHT_PAGE)
              return (
                <PaginateBtn
                  key={index}
                  aria-label="Next"
                  onClick={this.handleMoveRight}
                >
                  Suivant
                  <IconNext
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    className="h-4 w-4 inline-block ml-2"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M9 5l7 7-7 7"
                    />
                  </IconNext>
                </PaginateBtn>
              );

            return (
              <PaginateBtn
                key={index}
                onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(page, e)}
                activePage={currentPage === page}
              >
                {page}
              </PaginateBtn>
            );
          })}
        </PaginateWrapper>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Paginate.propTypes = {
  totalRecords: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  pageLimit: PropTypes.number,
  pageNeighbours: PropTypes.number,
  onPageChanged: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Paginate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data object passed to `onPageChanged` doesn't have a `selected` field, use `data.currentPage` instead

```
const currentPage = data.currentPage;
```